# How to convert rows to columns with case statement?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am accessing a WordPress database and I want to convert the rows to columns when I make a selection. That works so far but I don't know how to specify conditions.

**Table wp_usermeta**

```
| umeta_id | user_id | meta_key   | meta_value |
| -        | -       | -          | -          |
| 1        | 1       | first_name | james      |
| 2        | 1       | last_name  | wilson     |
| 3        | 1       | zip        | 83902      |
| 4        | 2       | first_name | mason      |
| 5        | 2       | last_name  | burton     |
| 6        | 2       | zip        | 29483      |
| 7        | 3       | first_name | jackson    |
| 8        | 3       | last_name  | owen       |
| 9        | 3       | zip        |            |
```

**Table wp_users**

```
| ID | user_email               |
| -  | -                        |
| 1  | james.wilson@example.com |
| 2  | mason.burton@example.com |
| 3  | jackson.owen@example.com |
```

```
select
  user_id,
  max(case when meta_key = 'first_name' then meta_value end) first_name,
  max(case when meta_key = 'last_name' then meta_value end) last_name,
  max(case when meta_key = 'zip' then meta_value end) postal_code,
  user_email as email
from `wp_usermeta`
left join `wp_users` on `wp_usermeta`.`user_id` = `wp_users`.`ID`
group by `user_id`;
```

**Result**

```
| user_id | first_name | last_name | postal_code| email                    |
| -       | -          | -         | -          | -                        |
| 1       | james      | wilson    | 83902      | james.wilson@example.com |
| 2       | mason      | burton    | 29483      | mason.burton@example.com |
| 3       | jackson    | owen      | null       | jackson.owen@example.com |
```

I need conditions like this:

```
(case when meta_key = 'first_name' and meta_value = 'james' then 'good' else 'bad') test
```

> Error Code: 1055. Expression of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'wp_usermeta.meta_value' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
max(case when meta_key = 'first_name' and meta_value = 'james' then 'good' else 'bad' end) test
```

Returns always "good" (max).

Comment: Your second attempt evaluates the case expression for every row, and since one row will be good (row 1), then the max of this will return good because `good` > `bad`. I think what you are looking for requires two case expressions: `CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name' THEN meta_value END) = 'James' THEN 'good' ELSE 'bad' END` - Or presumably you actually want to filter data, in which case it would be - `HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name' THEN meta_value END) = 'James'`

Comment: The first is the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The meat_value has to be in the max

But honestly i don't know why you want hat at all, with this query

> ```
> CREATE TABLE wp_usermeta
>     (`umeta_id` varchar(1), `user_id` varchar(1), `meta_key` varchar(10), `meta_value` varchar(7))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO wp_usermeta
>     (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
> VALUES
>
>     ('1', '1', 'first_name', 'james'),
>     ('2', '1', 'last_name', 'wilson'),
>     ('3', '1', 'zip', '83902'),
>     ('4', '2', 'first_name', 'mason'),
>     ('5', '2', 'last_name', 'burton'),
>     ('6', '2', 'zip', '29483'),
>     ('7', '3', 'first_name', 'jackson'),
>     ('8', '3', 'last_name', 'owen'),
>     ('9', '3', 'zip', NULL)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE wp_users
>     (`ID` varchar(1), `user_email` varchar(24))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO wp_users
>     (`ID`, `user_email`)
> VALUES
>
>     ('1', 'james.wilson@example.com'),
>     ('2', 'mason.burton@example.com'),
>     ('3', 'jackson.owen@example.com')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select
>   user_id,
>   max(case when meta_key = 'first_name' and meta_value = 'james' then meta_value end) first_name,
>   max(case when meta_key = 'last_name' and meta_value = 'james' then meta_value end) last_name,
>   max(case when meta_key = 'zip' and meta_value = 'james' then meta_value end) postal_code,
>   user_email as email
> from `wp_usermeta`
> left join `wp_users` on `wp_usermeta`.`user_id` = `wp_users`.`ID`
> group by `user_id`,user_email;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | first_name | last_name | postal_code | email                   
> :------ | :--------- | :-------- | :---------- | :-----------------------
> 1       | james      | null      | null        | james.wilson@example.com
> 2       | null       | null      | null        | mason.burton@example.com
> 3       | null       | null      | null        | jackson.owen@example.com
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a9747d84d92fcff31154e2ce6b05cac)*